# Java leaking private data memory. Any idea?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

I have an app SWING+JNI. It is leaking private set memory but no leaks in JAVA heap.

If I put it under stress test, the private set grows to 1G+ (reported by task manager and WIM_MAP tool) and app crashes with "out of memory" error. At the same time java heap is under 300 MB, there are not leaks at all.

I tried to do the same with just C++ code and there is no leak.

The data between JNI and Java is transferred with DirectBuffer but we reuse the same memory space so should be no leak there. 
I tried to run it with C++ and JNI wrapper with no SWING and there is no leak.

At this point im stuck. There is defiantly memory leak of native data but it shows up with SWING+JNI only.

I proved the same with Wim-Map tool.

Any advise or technique to continue investigation?

Comment: Do you free native resources in the Java class frontends? This is one of the rare cases where you may have to actually implement `.finalize()`.

Comment: The [Boehm garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector) in leak detection mode may help.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. The native resources are responsible for polling 3rd party C++ API for data and putting the data to DirectBuffer. It does not create any Java objects to finalize.